# How to check for output of command in Make rule?

Tags: php, makefile

between my lint and unit tests, i want to check if any php file generates any output.

i'm trying something like this, which obviously do not work:

```
.PHONY: php_inc
php_inc:
    ifneq (,$(shell php -e src/*inc))
        $(error PHP include files should not have any output when parsed)
    endif
```

suggestions on how to write this, or better way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this, to avoid executing `php` twice:

```
@output=`php -e src/*inc`; \
if [ ! -z "$$output" ]; then \
 echo "PHP include files should not output. Got:"; \
 echo $$output; \
 exit 1; \
fi
```

I don't know at which point the output can get too large for the shell to handle. Whenever I've had to work around tools whose status I had to check based on output rather than exit status, the output was rather modest.

Comment: right. could go even further and not silence the first run. and then the message could just say "fix the above output leak" or something. but the gripe is with the bash if instead of a make construct. any idea how to do this more make-like?

Answer (score 0):

documenting my current work around:

```
@if [ ! -z "`php -e src/*inc`" ]; then \
    echo "PHP include files should not output. Got:"; \
    php -e src/*inc; \
    exit 1; \
fi
```

or a little more make-like... but i like the quotes there. give me a warm sense of security :)

```
@if [ ! -z $(shell $(PHP) -e src/*inc) ]; then \
```